# Do I need to install Intellij after downloading Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am downloading Android Studio now so I can create mobile apps using Kotlin and I am totally new to it, I checked the Android Studio user guide and it says it is strongly built on IntelliJ so I am wondering do I still need to download IntelliJ or once I download Android Studio, I will find all I want in it.

Comment: No it works completely on its own

Comment: Android Studio is IntelliJ with Android-specific development tools and plugins installed on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio has built-in plugins with IntelliJ software. You don't need to install IntelliJ. Android Studio will work just fine.